# jQuery - Adding Multiple Select Dropdown Option Attributes Together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html for 2 select dropdowns:

```
<select name="options[4614]" id="select_4614" class="required product-custom-option admin__control-select" title="" data-selector="options[4614]" aria-required="true">
<option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="18923" money="100">Option 1</option>
<option value="18924" money="200">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select name="options[2433]" id="select_2433" class="required product-custom-option admin__control-select" title="" data-selector="options[2433]" aria-required="true">
<option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="9353" money="0">Option A</option>
<option value="9351" money="100">Option B</option>
<option value="9352" money="200">Option C</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to add together the values in the attribute 'money' for each selected option and then output this is another div.

I am using the below as a guide:

```
$(function () {
        var fields = $('.product-custom-option.admin__control-select').change(calculate);
        function calculate() {
            var pricesum = 0;
            fields.each(function () {
                pricesum += +$(this).val();
            })
            $('.outputdiv').html(pricesum.toFixed(2));
        }
    })
```

Which adds the option values together, but when changing .val to .attr('money') it returns NaN (not a number).

Any guidance on what is going wrong would be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your calculate function as below (commented for better understanding):

```js
$(function() {
  var fields = $('.product-custom-option.admin__control-select').change(calculate);

  function calculate() {
    var pricesum = 0;
    fields.each(function() {
    
      //this refers to select elements not options in this context
      //get selected option
      let money = +$(this.selectedOptions[0]).attr("money");
      
      //skip not selected values
      if (Number(money)===money) pricesum += money;
    })
    //console.log(pricesum)
    $('.outputdiv').html(pricesum.toFixed(2));
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="options[4614]" id="select_4614" class="required product-custom-option admin__control-select" title="" data-selector="options[4614]" aria-required="true">
  <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
  <option value="18923" money="100">Option 1</option>
  <option value="18924" money="200">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select name="options[2433]" id="select_2433" class="required product-custom-option admin__control-select" title="" data-selector="options[2433]" aria-required="true">
  <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
  <option value="9353" money="0">Option A</option>
  <option value="9351" money="100">Option B</option>
  <option value="9352" money="200">Option C</option>
</select>
<div class="outputdiv"></div>
```